# Selenium: send_keys Not Working with Firefox

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I'm using a raspberry pi 3 to run the following (this is just the relevant snippet):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://remind.com/log_in")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("uid")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("my@email.com")
pas = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
pas.clear()
pas.send_keys("password")
pas.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "Composer"))
)
item = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Composer")
item.click()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys("test1234")
actions.perform()
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "AnnouncementComposer__sendButton___yTDA6"))
)
item2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("AnnouncementComposer__sendButton___yTDA6")
item2.click()
driver.quit()
```

However, `actions.send_keys("test1234")` is not working even though I am able to send keys for both the username and password. Running the same code with chromedriver on Mac works. There is no error message on the pi, so I am almost positive the error has to do with sending keys and not looking for elements. I am unsure why this error is occurring.

Comment: I had issues with Firefox some time ago and my solution was downgrading it to version 41.

Comment: I'm using iceweasel, so how would I downgrade?